# Conditionally exclude echo statements in ksh

Tags: shell, scripting, echo, ksh

I would like to have a verbose/non verbose mode in my KornShell (ksh) script.

In verbose, I need to execute the statements with

```
echo blah blah blah
```

But in non verbose I don't want to exclude those echo statements
Now I am guessing there is a better/elegant way to achieving this rather than using a global state of verbosity and doing an

```
if [[ $verbose eq 1 ]] ; then
    echo blah blah blah
fi
```

I am new to ksh and do not know all the tricks.
Will somebody suggest what can be done?

Answer (score 3):

This should just work with `ksh`, `bash` or any `POSIX` or bourne shell derivative:

```
$ debug=true
$ $debug && echo blah blah blah
blah blah blah
$ debug=false
$ $debug && echo blah blah blah
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Ooops, you said "ksh" but the concept is pretty similar....

You can do something like this:

```
export DEBUG=1
[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ] && echo hi
hi

export DEBUG=0
[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ] && echo hi
```

Or you can just execute the script with the "-xv" flags, either by changing the shebang line at the start

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
Line 1 of your script...
Line 2 of your script
```

or by executing the script like this:

```
bash -xv yourscript
```

Or, you could define a debug() function in your login/profile script and do the check in there.

Comment: There is no need for an environment variable, it will work without "`export` "

Answer (score 0):

Without further ado (valid in ksh and bash, not POSIX sh):

```
# function verbose()
# accepts on | off | an empty string | a message
# on|off changes the global variable _Verbose 
# Anything else will return the value of ${_Verbose}
# and (optionally) display a message (which cannot start with on or off)
#
# Use only as conditional for echo: verbose && echo ...

_Verbose=0
verbose() { 
    case ${1} in
    (on) _Verbose=1;;
    (off) _Verbose=0;;
    ("") ((_Verbose));;
    (*)  ((_Verbose)) && echo "$*"
    esac
} 


$ verbose on
$ verbose && echo "Here's a message"
Here's a message
$ verbose "And another one"
And another one
$
$ verbose off
$ verbose && echo "Here's a message"
$ verbose "And another one"
```